# Recaptcha and selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to pass the Recaptcha verification the problem I am facing is sometimes it checks without the images and most of the time it gives the images.
Is there a way or does someone know the requirement for Recaptcha to check without the images?
I cant disable the Recaptcha.
There is no point in having selenium if I will stop it to solve it manually.
My code :

```
SoftAssert Sa = new SoftAssert();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(20000));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String FormatMessageInformatife = "<font color='#73a9d0'></br><i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>- ";
        String FormatMessageError = "<font color='#bf3d27'></br><i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i>- ";
        String FormatMessageSucces = "<font color='#69c158'></br><i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i>-";
        WebElement ClkSignup = driver.findElement(By.id("toggle-button"));
        ClkSignup.click();
        WebElement ClkSubscribe = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"dialog-07zr\"]/div[@class=\"boutons-yellow\"]/a[1]/button"));
        ClkSubscribe.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='steps-title']/ul/li[@class='active'][1]/span[normalize-space(text())='Coordonnées']")));
        Boolean AccesSubscription = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='steps-title']/ul/li[@class='active'][1]/span[normalize-space(text())='Coordonnées']")).size() > 0;
        if(AccesSubscription == true) {
            Reporter.log(FormatMessageSucces + " Accessed Subscription </font>");
            WebElement TVAInput = driver.findElement(By.id("create_account_step1_tva"));
            sendHumanKeys(TVAInput,"FR75850236541");
            WebElement EmailInput = driver.findElement(By.id("create_account_step1_mail"));
            sendHumanKeys(EmailInput,"test2021test@gmail.com");
            WebElement PhoneInput = driver.findElement(By.id("create_account_step1_phone"));
            sendHumanKeys(PhoneInput,"0721547861");
            WebElement PwdInput = driver.findElement(By.id("create_account_step1_password_first"));
            sendHumanKeys(PwdInput,"Test07ZR");
            WebElement CPwdInput = driver.findElement(By.id("create_account_step1_password_second"));
            sendHumanKeys(CPwdInput,"Test07ZR");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            WebElement CaptchaClk = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", CaptchaClk);
            WebElement RBClk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"checkbox\"]/label"));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", RBClk);
            WebElement ClkNext = driver.findElement(By.id("bt"));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ClkNext);
            }else {
            Sa.assertEquals(false, true, "Wasn't abel to acces Subscription");
            ScreenShot(driver);
            Reporter.log(FormatMessageError + " Wasn't abel to acces Subscription</font>");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ReCaptcha to check without the images"? You should provide a browser screenshot of Recapta. What exactly happens after entering details email, Phone etc? how does the ReCaptcha appears & is blocking your automation? Please elaborate.

Comment: ReCaptcha varification serves to avoid web crawling. Selenium is kind of a webcrawler. If you need proceed some selenium test you need to ask webmaster how to baypass the recaptcha verification.

Comment: @MudassirHussain it clicks on the recaptcha and shows the image selection but very rarely it clicks on the checkbox and it validates without showing the images check

Comment: @pburgr webmaster you mean by that ?